# Access to variable 'this' in object

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to access the variable `this` inside the slider options object, but this is not working:

```
$('.slider').slider({
    prevButton: $(this).find('.prev'),
    nextButton: $(this).find('.next'),
});
```

But it works if I change that to this:

```
$('.slider').slider({
    prevButton: $('.slider').find('.prev'),
    nextButton: $('.slider').find('.next'),
});
```

Is `$(this)` not referring to `$('.slider')` when is within an object? If is that the case, how can I access to `this` so I refer specifically to the buttons that are inside of that target?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a function:

```
$('.slider').slider({
    prevButton: (function () {
                    return $(this).find('.prev');
                })(),
    nextButton: (function () {
                    return $(this).find('.next');
                })(),
});
```

Or, the best working method is using `.each()`:

```js
$(".slider").each(function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.slider({
    prevButton: $this.find('.prev'),
    nextButton: $this.find('.next')
  });
});
```